# Stop being responsive at a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I know this question sounds crazy, but I'm going to explain it.

I have a responsive website and all works OK, but when the width is too low (width < 500px) the website (which is still responsive) start to rearrange in such a way that I prefer to NOT being responsive anymore.

I'd like to know if there is a script or anything that can solve this.
 Please any help will be useful :)

Comment: Do you want it to scroll horizontally if width > 500px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a minimum width on the html / body

```
html, body {
min-width: 500px;
}
```

Making elements responsive is usually done by setting width to a percentage of parent elements. The above would be an easy fix, but it's possible there will be elements you need to style using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your css within media queries so that it only applies under particular conditions. E.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```